# AWS WAF update ip sets and rules specific to a region from lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, web-application-firewall

I am able to successfully update the WAF ip address rule set from lambda if the rule sets are Global (Cloudfront).

but if i create a rule set specific to region to be able to use it with APP ELB, the get-ip-set or list-ip-set api's are not retrieving the IP set specific to a region and hence I am not able to update these rule sets directly from lambda.

Is there any additional param that needs to be passed to be able to retrieve these rule sets that are region specific

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post the actual code problem which goes with this question.   http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

You need to be using the correct regional endpoint.  The WAF endpoint that works with CloudFront is essentially a different system than each of the regional endpoints that work with ALB -- and those are all independent of each other.

[Apparently](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/waf-regional/index.html) it's also an entirely different initial command, `aws waf-regional` rather than `aws waf` (your initial question, with dashes shown in `get-ip-set` implies AWS-CLI syntax).

See also http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#waf_region

Comment: Thanks Michael, I will check this